# Need help understanding why this format is used for variable declaration. Not public, Not private

Tags: angular, typescript

Now this is from me trying to figure out why I could not get my 'multi' selectiontype to work on the data table. I found the solution that in their demo it works but am unclear what scope this variable is being declared under.

```
export class MultiSelectionComponent {
  /* I always define the variable when declared as either
   Public or Private
   But if I do then the HTML template does not recognize the reference
   When I drop the declaration type the HTML template can see it
  */
  SelectionType = SelectionType;
```

Would someone explain why this is or provide the appropriate link to the information that discusses this?

I've looked through as much as I can and have not found an answer here on SO.

Comment: I believe they did it to use it in HTML. You can only refer to instance variables from HTML. Default is public in Typescript, afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave out the modifier, it's `public`.  From [the TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-by-default) (emphasis added):

> #### Public by default
>
> In our examples, we’ve been able to freely access the members that we declared throughout our programs. If you’re familiar with classes in other languages, you may have noticed in the above examples we haven’t had to use the word `public` to accomplish this; for instance, C# requires that each member be explicitly labeled `public` to be visible. **In TypeScript, each member is `public` by default.**
>
> You may still mark a member `public` explicitly.

So the code in your example is equivalent to:

```
export class MultiSelectionComponent {
   public SelectionType = SelectionType;
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. The issue is with the VM that I'm to use. It is so insanely slow that when I was trying to add the variable the html page in the editor was not seeing what the variable was referencing when it was set to public only when it was left without the scope did it see it. Today after rebooting it is now seeing the variable. Developing on a shared system that primarily for running servers is NOT a good dev environment.